# Extract number after specific word and first open parenthesis using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

i want to get a string from a sentence which starts with a word Id:

Letter received for the claim
Id: Sanjay Kumar (12345678 / NA123456789)
Dear Customer find the report

> op:      Id: Sanjay Kumar (12345678 / NA123456789)
>
> Exp op: 12345678

Code

```
  var regex = new Regex(@"[\n\r].*Id:\s*([^\n\r]*)");
  var useridText = regex.Match(extractedDocContent).Value;
```

Comment: Maybe `(?<=Id:[^()]*\()\d+`? See https://regex101.com/r/aoYCiu/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=Id:[^()]*\()\d+");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aoYCiu/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=Id:[^()]*\()` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `Id:` + zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` + `(`
- `\d+` - one or more digtis.

Consider also a non-lookbehind approach:

```cs
var pattern = @"Id:[^()]*\((\d+)";
var useridText = Regex.Match(extractedDocContent, pattern)?.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: can we check the numbers which contains 8 to 10 numeric characters. min of 8 an max of 10 digits

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Yes, `(?<=Id:[^()]*\()\d{8,10}(?!\d)`.